# Как сделать выборку за эту неделю с понедельника

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер, делаю выборку из базы по дате за неделю, неделя начинается с воскресенья, нужно сделать с понедельника.

Выборку делаю так:

```
SELECT *
    FROM `tbl_name`
WHERE 
    `date` > DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL( DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE() ) -1 ) DAY )
AND 
    `date` < DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL( 9 - DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE() ) ) DAY )
```

Comment: если записей за будущие даты нет, то можно обойтись без верхней граници

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку =) Разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...where date > curdate() - datofweek() +1;

Comment: Так мне говорит об ошибке функции.

Уже разобрался.. =)

Comment: да я фукнкций не помню, просто показал логику, что бы от даты отнять сегоднешний день недели... и будет дата начала недели

Comment: Ну я так и понял, ошибка была после того как я поправил названия..